# Apache ivy with Eclipse and multiple projects

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, ivy, multiple-projects

How I can use ivy to resolve dependencys between different Eclipse projects?

I have one project which has librarys and base classes that I want to use in another project. Like a spring base project and a project which uses spring.

In Eclipse there are "deploymentassemblies" but if I use that, I only got the class files in the other project, but not the librarys I added, with a ivy.xml, to the base project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IvyDE](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/) Eclipse plugin to resolve dependencies in Eclipse Project. Once IvyDE is installed, you will have the option to "Add Ivy Library..." when you right click on a project's `ivy.xml`. Once configured, IvyDE will resolve the project's dependecies and add them to the project's classpath.